# Sequence of triangles divided into 10 smaller triangles with yellow, purple, and/or dots

Tags: visual, sequence

This is IQ type of puzzle. May not be progressive sequence.
[image: puzzle]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 2

because

> there is always as many circles as yellow/purple edges. The circles are colored with the color most triangles have.

Comment: Is this actually true? It only really seems to hold for the second image, and the fourth if white is considered a tie. The third doesn't even have a circle...

Comment: It holds for all of them if you consider rot13(gur ahzore bs rqtrf funerq ol n lryybj naq n checyr gevnatyr). But I do agree it seems a bit too complicated to be a satisfying answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's not how I read your answer. I interpreted your words as meaning 'yellow vs purple edges [of the big triangle]', in which case we'd have (in order) 1P0Y, 0P2Y, 1P3Y, 2P2Y and 3P0Y. Whereas you meant rot13(obhaqnel rqtrf orgjrra n lryybj gevnatyr naq n checyr gevnatyr) - I get you now, thanks.